# MySQL status update trigger on delete

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

I want to see your opinion on this issue.

I'm using MySQL database for my projects, and in almost every table, I have a column called **Status** defined (ENUM('active','inactive','deleted')).

I do this for performance reasons, so whenever a row is not needed(deleted), I set it to 'deleted' instead of actually deleting it from the DB. This has proven fairly good.

But, now I always have to write PHP functions in my projects for updating a row from Active to Deleted.

What do you think, how can I solve this using MySQL triggers or using other technique?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's wrong about updating a row to set it to deleted?

After all,

```
UPDATE projects SET status = 'deleted' WHERE id = :id;
```

vs

```
DELETE FROM projects WHERE id = :id;
```

do not make much of a difference or does it?

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is not much difference between writing;

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE id = 1
```

or

```
UPDATE table SET status = 'deleted' WHERE id = 1
```

As soon as you create the same field with the same name in all of your tables, a trigger function doesn't seem that necessery to me.

Comment: Sorry, I accidently edited your answer instead of mine. Just rolled it back. Nice to see, that our answers are almost the same. Therefore, I didn't notice :).

Answer (score 0):

You always have to make a request from your application code to your database to implement your application use case. Whether this is an actual DELETE statement for a row, or an UPDATE statement that sets the status to 'deleted' does not really matter. You cannot circumvent this with some sort of trigger.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you're trying to achieve..

If you won't ever need the row again once its been deleted, then you should just delete it - updating the status column doesn't really do much for you. Performance-wise, it's probably going to be better if you physically delete the row (depending, of course, on the actual structure of your database)..

If you do need to keep the record around after it has been deleted, then you could create an archive table which you write a copy of the record to when you delete it from your main table. The copy would be written by an on-delete trigger..

Either way, you'll always have to make a database call, either to delete the record, or to update the status to deleted..